# How to Disable Highchart Unit Display None

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to have a Highcharts - Spiderweb like [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/) but I need to Update/hard code the yAxis values. I also need to stylize them the color, font and size. can you please let me know how? Is there any way to stop displaying the default units and only display the chart?

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -80
        },

        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 
                    'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual Spending',
            data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]

    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.                        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Budget vs spending',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
             return null;
          }
        },
        title: {
            text: '10'
        },            
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]

 });
});
```

you can also check http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors for color and style